# php uploads $_FILES[FileName]["tmp_name"] uniqueness

Tags: php, file, upload, location, temporary

I can't find specific information as to the uniqueness of `$_FILES["FileName"]["tmp_name"]`.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php 
I see that 6 hex characters are what make the file name unique.
e.g. `/tmp/php/php6hst32`

From local testing (**XAMPP** | **WIN 7**) I see only 4 hex characters
e.g. `\tmp\phpCC07.tmp`

This would suggest a min uniqueness of `1` in `65536` which doesn't seem that unique to me.

Where is this set within PHP? (it's not in `php.ini`). Is it hard coded or can it be configured?

I realise that a clash could only happen within a brief period since the file should last only the duration of the script but these odds don't offer the comfort I was expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are guaranteed to be unique. PHP uses `GetTempFileName()` on Windows and `mkstemp()` or `mktemp()` on Linux.

`GetTempFileName()` produces filenames of the format <prefix>XXXX. (This is what you see with XAMPP)

`mkstemp()` and `mktemp()` produce filenames of the format <prefix>XXXXXX. (This is what was in the docs)

These are not configurable, they are set by the system's standard C library. The system guarantees that the filenames that are generated are unique. If the system is unable to create a unique filename, the function call returns an error status to PHP which in turn raises an `E_WARNING`: "File upload error - unable to create a temporary file".

References:

- PHP 5.6 source: [rfc1867.c](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/main/rfc1867.c#1011), [php_open_temporary_file.c](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/main/php_open_temporary_file.c#php_do_open_temporary_file)
- [mkstemp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp), [mktemp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktemp)
- [GetTempFileName()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks mixedreturns for a nice clear explanation. I'm re-assured by the fallback of an E_WARNING in the event of a temporary name clash. Philosophically I feel 1:65,535 odds of a clash in windows are too high but at least my app won't end up putting files in the wrong place.